# ignore jslint 'unnecessary escapement' error for unicode escape sequences

Tags: javascript, jslint

I have a javascript string like this:

```
"arc\u007ccommunity blog post."
```

which jslint reports as an 'unnecessary escapement' error.

How can I tell JSLint to ignore this?

---

Background:
The reason we don't just have the string:

```
"arc|community blog post."
```

in the source code, is that the code is generated using a t4 template, and we are using the | character in the generation source as a delimiter.

Comment: I've just seen your edit. One way around this would be to switch to JSHint which doesn't check strings for escape sequences at all. Also, out of interest, what version of JSLint are you using?

Comment: We've been using JSLint for a couple of years and it generally working well for us, so I don't think we want to change to JSHint. I will probably just decide to exclude generated code from the JSLint process. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Your version of JSLint seems to be about 4 years old so I would recommend updating if you can! Looks like the message changed from "Bad escapement" sometime in 2010.

Comment: The actual warning is 'Unnecessary escapement'. And now I look closely, I see we have JSHint. We are calling it over the command line using SharpLinter.

Comment: Yes, sorry, "Bad escapement" is what JSHint used for the same situation ages ago (it's since been removed). I've added a page for this error to [jslinterrors.com](http://jslinterrors.com/unnecessary-escapement). If there's anything you'd like to add to it please let me know or send a pull request.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JSLint is giving you that error because you're using a unicode escape sequence to represent a character that can be represented normally. In your case you should be able to replace the string with the following:

```
"arc|community blog post."
```

The following is the [function used inside JSLint](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSLint/blob/a2935fbda12c4c2de57de1761d4a50c166a5b3ce/jslint.js#L865) to find allowable unicode escape sequences. If you use one that is not in the given ranges you will get the "Unnecessary escapement" error (or "Unexpected '\'" in the latest version):

```
function hex(n) {
    var i = parseInt(source_row.substr(at + 1, n), 16);
    at += n;
    if (i >= 32 && i <= 126 &&
            i !== 34 && i !== 92 && i !== 39) {
        warn('unexpected_a', line, character, '\\');
    }
    character += n;
    ch = String.fromCharCode(i);
}
```

Unfortunately there is no way to switch off this check.